# PL/SQL passing functions as parameters

Tags: function, parameters, plsql, functional-programming

I've programmed in PL/SQL during half an year and I had the impression it's a quite plain programming language (IMHO). Although I've stumbled upon interesting articles, like this one - [Design Patterns in PL/SQL – Interface Injection for even looser coupling](http://technology.amis.nl/2006/03/11/design-patterns-in-plsql-interface-injection-for-even-looser-coupling/), I recommend reading. Talking about dependency injection, I miss an special feature: passing subroutines as parameters. Is it possible? How?

For instance, imagine I have a code like this in javascript:

```
function tell_me (printer) {
  printer ("hello");
}

tell_me (function () {
  console.log (word);
});
```

Is it possible to do something similar in PL/SQL?

Comment: If you need to pass a subroutine as a parameter in PL/SQL, you should probably reexamine your problem - does it really need to be solved in PL/SQL??

Comment: @NWest, you're right, altough that's one possible way of loose coupling two subroutines. The truth is, I asked it out of curiosity, just to explore a little bit more details of PL/SQL.

Comment: @NWest, I cited reflective programming and here's an actual problem (I know I'm deviating a little bit, but it worth): my pl/sql modules should call a REST API, with huge XMLs. I don't want to build each XML by hand, so I mapped each entity in a TYPE. Is is possible to get a type's fields, alter them during runtime, without knowing the type that has been passed to my routine?

With that I can build a module to convert XML to PL/SQL types (and vice versa). Changes in the API's types would only require maintenance in PL/SQL types, instead of maitaning whole one conversino function to each type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't pass a function as a parameter directly. The best you could do is use dynamic PL/SQL to execute a function passed in as a string. I do not recommend this. I can see the use of dynamic PL/SQL in a few cases, but this opens you up to all sorts of problems.

```
DECLARE 
   PROCEDURE inner_function
   IS
   BEGIN
       dbms_output.put_line('Output');
   END;

   PROCEDURE tell_me(parm_function varchar2) 
   IS
   BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN '||parm_function||'(); END;';
   END;

BEGIN
   tell_me('inner_function');
END;
```

DBMS_OUTPUT should just have "Output" in the buffer.

This may not work since inner_function may be out of scope. In that case, define the procedure in the schema itself.