# Can I return a function in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, stored-functions

I am trying to return a function in PL/SQL. Can I do so?

```
FUNCTION my_func () RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
 BEGIN
  RETURN 'any other function'
 END;
```

Comment: I would recommend you return the result of the function instead of return the function itself

Comment: Hi, makes no sense .. maybe you want to return the result of another function, but not a function.

Comment: You can return an object, and that object can have methods. Is that what you mean? Some more details of what you’re looking for would help.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49931697/409172) question or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11130610/409172)?

Answer (score 0):

Function must return [expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions001.htm#i1002626),

> An expression is a combination of one or more values, operators, and SQL **functions that evaluates to a value**

You can return [Function expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions007.htm)

> You can use any built-in SQL function or user-defined function as an expression. Some valid built-in function expressions are:
>
> ```
> LENGTH('BLAKE') 
> ROUND(1234.567*43) 
> SYSDATE
> ```

Answer (score -1):

--Create your function:

```
create or replace function my_func return VARCHAR2 is
begin
  return 'any other function';
end my_func;
```

--Test function:

```
declare 
  v_return varchar2(100);
begin
  v_return:=my_func;
  dbms_output.put_line('v_return: '||v_return);
end;
```

v_return ==> any other function